# add same footnote (duplicated number)

Tags: libreoffice-writer, footnote

It is possible duplicate a footnote in libreoffice? I am not interested in creating a new number for the same note.

***page 1***

some text-
something¹

__

¹ This is a note

---

***page 2***

some text- something ¹

__

¹ This is the same note

Basically, keep the same footnote.

Comment: just add in a footer and type some text - something 1.

Comment: @cutrightjm Who's going to update that when more footnotes come into play? Not really a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this only to a very limited extend. The easiest way would be **not** to **number** those two footnotes, but to use any **character as footnote symbol**. Then you could choose the same character for both footnotes. You could even use a number as manually-assigned character, but then the trouble starts if there are more, numbered footnotes in the same document. Because then, you have to take care not to get three footnotes with the same number (two manually-assigned and on auto-numbered).

Personally, i would recommend **not** to use same numbers for two footnotes, but to use cross-references. You can cross-reference both the footnote number and the page where that footnote is located. So, in your case i would insert two "standard" footnotes with different numbering, and put a textual cross-reference in the second one: "`See footnote <number> at page <page-number>.`"

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to create just one footnote for the first instance and, in place of adding additional footnotes at the other locations, just put cross-references to the original footnote. Then you can also change the style of these particular cross-references to subscript so that, visually, they'll look the same as regular footnote.

Comment: Works quite well actually.